# Accessing a 2D vector using push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am currently declaring my vector as follows

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> test(5, std::vector<int>(2,0));`

I then access it like this

`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        std::cin >> test[i][0];
        std::cin >> test[i][1];
    }
```

`
Since the vector is static (5 Rows, with 2 columns), I would like to make it variable (rows variable, column staitc) by using push_back. However, I don't know how to access the individual columns. Maybe someone can help me.

I already tried to access it with
`test.at(i).at(0)` and
`test.at(i).at(1)` but it wont work.
Although I found this solution
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >nns;
int i = 5;
nns.push_back(std::vector<int> {i});
for(int i = 0; i <nns.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < nns[i].size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << nns[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
}
```

` but there you have to define a static size (int i = 5).

Comment: its not clear what you are looking for. YOu seem to know how to construct the vector with a given size and how to push elements later on. Thats basically the two options you have. Trying to access elements that are beyond the size via `[]` is undefined behavior, the vectors do not magically resize

Comment: are you perhaps looking for `nns[i].push_back(42);` ? pushing to the inner vector works the same as pushing something to the outer vectors

Comment: i want to define a 2D-vector, like this 'std::vector<std::vector<int>> test' and write an undefind number of X,Y pairs on it. Later i want to access these X,Y pairs like 'std::cout << test[n][0]', where the 0 discribes X, and 'std::cout << test[n][0]', where the 1 discribes Y. The n stands for a row in my vector

Comment: Great, sounds like a plan. But what, exactly is your specific question? There's nothing in your description that's any different than the code that's already shown, so it's not clear what you're asking. Try to pretend that a complete stranger walked off the street and is standing in front of you. This stranger has no knowledge of what you're trying to do. You would like to ask a stranger a technical C++ question. What is your question?>

Comment: If you want the elements of `test` to be an x and y coordinate, why not define `struct point { int x; int y; };` and have `std::vector<point>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know how to push a vector into the vector of vectors. You wrote this:

> ```
> nns.push_back(std::vector<int> {i});
> ```

You do not have to specifiy the size `i` here, you can push an empty vector

```
nns.push_back({});
```

Now `nns` has a single element. `nns[0]` has `0` elements. Pushing elements to `nns[0]` works exactly the same, just that its elements are not vectors but integers:

```
nns[0].push_back(42);
```

If you do that `m`-times then `nn[0]` will have `m` elements. Also `resize` works on the inner as well as on the outer vectors. For example to get `n` elements (vectors) each with `m` elements (integers):

```
nns.resize(n);
for (int i=0; i<nn.size(); ++i) nns[0].resize(m);
```

TL;DR There is nothing special about nested vectors. The outer vectors work exactly the same as the inner vectors. You can construct them with or without elements and you can push elements or resize them.

Comment: That is a great explanation. That helps me a lot to understand what this nested push_back structure does. Thank you very much !